# docker compose not linking correctly

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have what I believe to be a fairly straightforward docker compose file. I have a mongo container, and in a second container I run a script to seed the DB with data.

```
version: '2'
services:
   employer:
      build:
         context: ..
      ports:
         - "9000:80"
      depends_on:
         - db
      links:
         - db
      environment:
         NODE_ENV: "test"
         MONGODB_URL: "mongodb://db:27017/my-service"
      command: node bin/data-sync.js import --db mongodb://db:27017/my-service -f test/integration/fixtures.json -c collectionName
   db:
      image: mongo
```

Unfortunately this fails with the following error:

> { Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN db:27017
>       at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:953:11)
>       at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
>       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)   name: 'MongoError',   message: 'getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN db:27017' }

This suggests it can't translate the "db" to anything sensible. However, I have followed the docs:

> Containers for the linked service will be reachable at a hostname
>   identical to the alias, or the service name if no alias was specified.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links

Any suggestions?

Comment: In what environment do you run Docker? Maybe restarting Docker or Docker Machine VM helps

Comment: Skip compose, fire up mongo manually, fire up the 2nd one with a shell prompt and step through it.

Comment: @user2105103, I have. This was the natural progression.

Comment: @Lauri, I am using my desktop (Mac OSX). From your response, I am guessing you believe this should be working?

Comment: Not sure about the compose syntax, that's why I suggested firing them up the old school way to troubleshoot.   If you eliminate compose, does it work?  Can your app container ping db?   What does /etc/hosts look like?  etc, etc, etc.